# Android Custom content provider, cursor is returned as null if application is not running

Tags: android-contentprovider

I have 2 applications, Application 1 and Application 2. Application 1 implements a custom Content Provider to expose data. From Application 2 I am able to access data from Application 1 but only when application 1 is running in background.

When application 1 is killed or not running then how to access data in Application 2 ?

Using following code to fetch Cursor.

```
 Cursor c;
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    c = getContentResolver().query(
                            appUri,
                            null, null, null);
                } else {
                    c = managedQuery(appUri, null, null, null, null);
                }
```

When application 1 is not running at that time I get c as null in Application 2. But if Application 1 is running then I am able to fetch data in Application 2.